# Rxjs update a list depending on two observables

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

So basically what I'm trying to do is to update an array to display it, one of the observables is a Behavior subject that starts as an empty array and then it gets a new value from an HTTP request, the other is an event emitter from the Angular material paginator, the desired behavior is to update the list if the first observable gets a new array or if the second emits an event to change the page.

The firts thing i try was:

```
connect(): Observable<Transaction[]> {
     return this.paginator.page.pipe(
    map(() => {
       return this.list.pipe(map(t => this.getPagedData(t)));
    }),
    switchMap(m => m) // or mergeMap
);
}
```

And it sort of works, the problem is that the first time it does not emit anything because it waits for the outer observable to emit something, then it works.

then I try

```
return merge(this.list, this.paginator.page).pipe(
  map(x => this.getPagedData(x[0])),
);
```

But this one only seems to emit the first time when the array is empty

Comment: what is the definition of the this.paginator.page ?

Comment: Is an angular material component call Matpaginator and the page property is an observable of page event wich has things like the index of the page , size of the page and other thing but in short it's just another observable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `startWith` operator, which will emit a value (default is null) even if the source observable didn't emit the first value.

From RxJs documentation:

**startWith** - Returns an Observable that emits the items you specify as arguments before it begins to emit.

So you will have something like this

```
connect(): Observable<Transaction[]> {
   return this.paginator.page.pipe(
      startWith(),
      map(() => this.list.pipe(map(t => this.getPagedData(t))),
      switchMap(m => m) // or mergeMap
  );
}
```

Comment: yes thanks it work just like i need it, now i can finally remove this code  
this.subscription = this.paginator.page.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('update from pager');
      this.list.next(this.list.getValue());
    });
    return this.list.pipe(map(l => this.getPagedData(l)));

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) Please try with this code change.

```
return combineLatest(this.list, this.paginator.page).pipe(
  map(x => this.getPagedData(x[0])),
);
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work, it keeps on reprodusing the same bahavior, actually its kind of what happents with merger

Answer (score 0):

I think your first approach makes sense but just need the `this.paginator.page` to have an initial value to emit. I suggest to wrap it up like the following

```
this.page=this.paginator.page.pipe(startWith(1),shareReplay(1))
```

use `this.page` for outer stream instead then you always have an start value and notified with the updates too